# RelativeLayout causes lag on Listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory-management

Just to make sure that the `RelativeLayout` causes the lag I replaced it will a simple layout, then no lags experienced.

I am using [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/demo/stock/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/demo/fragment/ListGplayCardFragment.java).

I have no nested layout on the rel layout **2-level hierarchy**, but still I am getting lags when I used it. Are there any options messing up or priority options messed up?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip">

     <!--  This is the base Inner View inside a CardHeader.
         You can customize it with your layout xml file and your CardHeader.
         You can popolate your elements with CardHeader#setupInnerViewElements(android.view.ViewGroup, android.view.View) method
    -->


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/card_activated"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_header_inner_simple_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/card_activated"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>


  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/content_picture" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
         android:entries="@array/quanitiy"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDisplay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/card_activated"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/card_activated"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_header_inner_simple_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Total" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageDisplay"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDisplay"
        android:text="$ 10"
        android:textColor="@color/light_green"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checkout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/checkout" />

     <AutoCompleteTextView
         android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_header_inner_simple_title"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
         android:alpha=".4"
         android:ems="9"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Add optional note to chef"
         android:textColor="@color/abs__background_holo_dark"
         android:textStyle="italic" >

         <requestFocus />
     </AutoCompleteTextView>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageDisplay"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:text="Red Horse"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/subtotal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/checkout2"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="$ 10"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Update:

```
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    Viewholder v = new Viewholder();
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(!imageLoader.isInited()){

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity())); 

    }

    if(rowView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_base_header_cutom, null);
         v.img = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
         v.remove = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);


         //Viewholder viewHolder = new Viewholder();

         rowView.setTag( v);
    }
    else{
        v = (Viewholder) rowView.getTag();
    }


     if(v.img!=null && imageLoader != null){
            imageLoader.displayImage("http://assets.bigdealsmedia.net/images/13407.jpg",  v.img, options);   

     }
     v.remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            remove(list.get(position));

            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            //

        }
    });


    return rowView;
  }
```

Comment: post the adapter code. layout probabky has nothing to do with this

Comment: I am using cardslib. I added a link above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the item, check your listview width/height they should both be set to match_parent. Setting the listview width to wrap_content kills your render times.

You generally want to avoid wrap_content on any xml layout. Try setting the parent element's width and height to match_parent as well, and for some of the children views you can probably atleast set the width to match_parent.

maybe post some of the getView() code from your adapter as well.

Also change your inflation from this

```
 rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_base_header_cutom, null);
```

to this

```
 rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_base_header_cutom, parent,false);
```

Comment: Thanks for a very useful tips! I got `wrap_content` only on listview height, so I changed that. I added the code for my adapter

Comment: By the way, In which part of the documentation did you learn the `match_parent` vs `content_wrap` rendering? I wanted to learn more.

Comment: It was in a google io presentation by one of the core android developers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70  basically wrap_content has to measure atleast twice before its drawn, usually a lot. I probably increased the efficiency of my adapters 100 fold. Use view holders, and for your images have some sort of caching, LRU cache is super easy to use. Check out my edited solution

Comment: Does this mean that `wrap_content` could eat up the memory while its being rendered a couple of times, right?

Comment: I dont know how much memory it consumes but onMeasure will be called multiple times for views with wrap_content

Comment: one last tip, in your adapter, I would just get the layoutInflater when the class first loads and reference it instead of each time in getView(), not sure how big of a performance increase that will be but  it should help

Comment: Just imagine a whole bunch of `warp_content` on my application, this will be scary. I will be optimizing my codes on this end.

Comment: the only time you're going to notice is in something like a listview otherwise the performance is negligible

Comment: Very very helpful! you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

In my few experimentation, the library does not cater heavy UI.

So what I did, I just used a simple listview, then in my cutom array adapter i still used viewholder class, and use a style to look the layout like a card.